# Java unreliable RSA encryption/decryption of strings

Tags: java, string, encryption, rsa

I have a very annoying problem with the unreliable encryption and decryption of string with the RSA algorithm in Java. It seams to only work about 35% of the times, and I can't figure out why it sometimes does work and sometimes don't. Here's some test-code I wrote to try to verify the randomness in the encryption/decryption. It runs 100 laps and it encrypts and decrypts the same string every time and prints the number of times it was successful:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte[] dataToEncrypt = "Hello World!".getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    byte[] cipherData = null;
    byte[] decryptedData;

    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(512);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    Key publicKey = kp.getPublic();
    Key privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    RSAPublicKeySpec pub = (RSAPublicKeySpec) fact.getKeySpec(publicKey,
            RSAPublicKeySpec.class);

    RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(pub.getModulus(), pub
            .getPublicExponent());
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    PublicKey publicKeyRSA = factory.generatePublic(spec);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKeyRSA);
            cipherData = cipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("Encrypt error");
        }

        String s = new String(cipherData, "UTF-16LE");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        try {
            decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(s.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
            System.out.println("Decrypted: "
                    + new String(decryptedData, "UTF-16LE"));
            k += 1;
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("Decrypt error");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of correct decryptions is: " + k);

}
```

I've tried to initialize the KeyPairGenerator with various values without any success.

Edit:
Now it works like a charm, thanks to [Base64](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/):

```
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.security.Key;
    import java.security.KeyFactory;
    import java.security.KeyPair;
    import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
    import java.security.PublicKey;
    import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;

    public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte[] dataToEncrypt = "Hello World!".getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    byte[] cipherData = null;
    byte[] decryptedData;


    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(512);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    Key publicKey = kp.getPublic();
    Key privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    RSAPublicKeySpec pub = (RSAPublicKeySpec) fact.getKeySpec(publicKey,
            RSAPublicKeySpec.class);

    RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(pub.getModulus(), pub
            .getPublicExponent());
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    PublicKey publicKeyRSA = factory.generatePublic(spec);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKeyRSA);
            cipherData = cipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("Encrypt error");
        }

        String s = Base64.encodeBytes(cipherData);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        try {
            decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(s));
            System.out.println("Decrypted: "
                    + new String(decryptedData, "UTF-16LE"));
            k += 1;
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("Decrypt error");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of correct decryptions is: " + k);

}
```

}

Comment: Typically you don't encrypt user data(such as strings) directly with RSA. But you rather create a random symmetric key, use that key to encrypt the actual user data, and only encrypt the key with RSA. It's not the cause of your immediate problem, but you should keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem, or at least *a* problem:

```
String s = new String(cipherData, "UTF-16LE");
```

You're taking *arbitrary binary data* and trying to create a string from it, treating it as if it's UTF-16-encoded text. It's not. It's arbitrary binary data.

*Either* keep it in binary form (as `byte[]`) or use base64 to convert it to text in a safe, reversible manner. ([This public domain base64 encoder](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) has a reasonable API, for example.)

Answer (score 4):

Probably because you convert the encrypted bytestream into UTF16-LE, which you should not do.